# Derivative of a series

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having trouble with a homework (so no full solutions please) question. Having trouble starting, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

f(x) = x - $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ + $\frac{x^5}{5!}$ - $\frac{x^7}{7!}$ + ... Find the smallest value of n such that f$^{(n)}$ = f(x).

I am unsure how to handle this since it appears to be a series.

Comment: With some caveats about convergence (assuming you're not working in formal power series), you can differentiate a series term-by-term.

Comment: If you know what this is the Maclaurin series _for_, you can probably answer the question (for _positive_ $ \ n \ $) without any differentiation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For power series like this, it turns out that you can differentiate term-by-term; the formal justification takes a bit of work - but for this series, the radius of convergence is infinite, so differentiating termwise will work.

To get you started, note that

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} x - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^5}{5!} - \dots \\
&= 1 - \frac{3 x^2}{3!} + \frac{5x^4}{5!} - \dots \\
&= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \dots
\end{align*}

Comment: This might seem like a stupid question, but I understand your second line, but how do you get from your second line to the third?

Comment: @KarlSisto Use the fact that $$n! = n(n - 1)!$$ for all $n$.

Answer (score -2):

$n=0 {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Downvote?  Am I not correct?

Comment: The problem statement should probably specify that $ \ n \ $ is positive, because I would agree with you, but I don't think that was the _intended_ answer...